# Project Online ProjectData/Ressources bugged?

Tags: rest

When I call this URL for my Project Online instance :
https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/_api/ProjectData/

I get :

```
    <service xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xml:base="https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/_api/ProjectData/">
        <workspace>
            <atom:title>Default</atom:title>
            <collection href="Projets">
            <atom:title>Projets</atom:title>
            </collection>
            <collection href="PlanningsDeR%C3%A9f%C3%A9renceProjet">
            <atom:title>PlanningsDeRéférenceProjet</atom:title>
            </collection>
            <collection href="PlanningsR%C3%A9f%C3%A9renceAffectation">
            <atom:title>PlanningsRéférenceAffectation</atom:title>
            </collection>
            <collection href="JeuDonn%C3%A9esChronologiquesR%C3%A9f%C3%A9renceAffectation">
            <atom:title>JeuDonnéesChronologiquesRéférenceAffectation</atom:title>
            </collection>
            <collection href="JeuDonn%C3%A9esChronologiquesAffectation">
            <atom:title>JeuDonnéesChronologiquesAffectation</atom:title>
            </collection>
            ...
            <collection href="Ressources">
            <atom:title>Ressources</atom:title>
            </collection>
            ...
```

When I call any of these ( for example : https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/_api/ProjectData/Projets) all is ok, but when I call :
https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/_api/Ressources
I get :

```
    <m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <m:code/>
    <m:message xml:lang="fr-FR">Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de cette requête.</m:message>
    </m:error>
```

(generic error)

Does this happen to anyone ? As the fragements are translated, maybe it only happens in french, any french here to confirm ?

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this bug, I forced the api in english with [en-US]:

[https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/_api/ProjectData/[en-US]](https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/_api/ProjectData/%5Ben-US%5D)

then

[https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/_api/ProjectData/[en-US]/Resources](https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/_api/ProjectData/%5Ben-US%5D/Resources)

is working